Why is it that the Chad and Caspian Sea endorheic basins have not silted over?
It doesn't seem like the Persian Gulf where there's subduction in the Orogeny and the Pebas silted in just a few million years while the Chad and Caspian still exist and in the middle of continental plates that are not rifting into two distinct plates like in the African Great Lakes.
